ASP.NET Core Razor page (MVVM) not able to post back a complex data type
Is there a way to BindProperty on a complex type in ASP.NET Core and MVVM?
I'm having a problem binding back data from what a user selected on a webpage back to the callback method. Simple data types bind back correctly.
However I have a list of objects that do not bind. In the view, I added code to serialize the data of interest, added it to a hidden field, and can see in the debugger that it is included as apart of the post.
I need the bind to UDFDsSelected in the call back for my project to work.
_UDFDSelected.cshtml:
@using Data.Models;
@model FilterReport;

@{
    var serializedUDFDs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.UDFDsSelected?.Select(udfd => new { udfd.Code, udfd.Description }).ToList());
}

<input type="hidden" name="FilterReport.UDFDsSelected" id="UDFDsSelectedHidden" value="@serializedUDFDs" />

jQuery:
var formData = $('#frmReport').serializeArray();
$.post('/reports/AddUDFD',
    formData
).done(function (response)

Reports.cshtml.cs:
[BindProperty]
public FilterReport FilterReport { get; set; }

#region Public
public IActionResult OnPostAddUDFD(string UDFD, string description)
{
    // Do Work

    return new PartialViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "_UDFDList",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<FilterReport>(ViewData, FilterReport)
    };
}

FilterReport.cs:
public class FilterReport
{
    public string TimeZone { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<UDFD> UDFDsSelected { get; set; }
}

UDFD.cs:
public class UDFD
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

Debugger on serialized postback data:


Found a Work Around:
`// 1) In the model, I add a string version of the complex object:`

public string uDFDsSelectedString { get; set; }
public List<UDFD> uDFDsSelected { get; set; }

`// 2) In the view, serialize the complex object to the string version:
// and imbed it in the post back through a hidden field.`

var serializedUDFDs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.uDFDsSelected?.Select(udid => new { udfd.Code, udfd.Description }).ToList());
<input type="hidden" name="FilterReport.uDFDsSelectedString" value="@serializedUDFDs" />

`// 3) In the post back, deserialize the string version back into the complex object:`

string json = FilterReport.uDFDsSelectedString;
List <UDFD> udids = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UDFD>>(json);

